# Why is this matrix diagonalizable?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I know that is symmetric, but to diagonalize it we want to invert the matrix for $$P^{-1}AP=D$$ But we can't find the determinant of matrix A because $$\frac{1}{det(A)}$$ the denominator is zero.

Why is matrix A diagonalizable?

Comment: May I ask why you **need** to diagonalise this matrix?

Comment: $A$ is already diagonal ...

Comment: $P$ needs to be invertible, not $A$, and the determinant of $A$ plays no role.

Comment: @Qwerty Initially, we had a $$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
x & x & x \\
0 & x & x \\
0 & 0 & x
\end{bmatrix}
$$ matrix, and I ask which values of $x$ is matrix $A$ diagonalizable, and the only solution is when $x=0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right! I forgot.

Answer (score 3):

It is already a diagonal matrix. So P is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 1):

We have $P^{-1}AP=D$ with $D=A$ and $P=I_3$

$A$ is a diagonal matrix, hence diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then

$$
A v = 0 v
$$

So $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are all zeros, while the eigenvectors are arbitrary, you can use the vectors of the base so that $P = I_3$

Comment: Wouldn't a multiplicity of 3 by an argument against diagonalization?

Comment: Not at all, the matrix $I_3$ has all its eigenvalues equal to 1, and its diagonalizable